# MySQL Error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I couldn't find error.I use WAMP set up database.

MySQL said：

```
#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'SELECT * FROM `memberdata`' Ã  la ligne 1
```

When I enter SQL instruction:

```
"USE `member` SELECT * FROM `memberdata`"
```

I have two quetion：

1.Why is the system meaningless drivel?

2.I visited MYSQL official website,and find Error#1064.
It means：%s near '%s' at line %d.What does it mean?

Actually I am a tiro,there are many places to learn.
I hope you help me solve this problem.

Comment: put a ; after USE member

Comment: Thank you for your answer :  ).I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two commands. And ';' is the default delimiter of mysql. Demiliter have to be used between commands, when more than one is there

to select the DB ([more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html))

```
USE `member`;
```

to query from table ([more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html))

```
SELECT * FROM `memberdata`;
```

Following may work for you:-

```
    "USE `member`;SELECT * FROM `memberdata`;"
or
    "SELECT * FROM member.`memberdata`;"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Your answer is useful : ).